# iOS Core data - how to check before inserting

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, ios4

I am using the core data in my application.
I know how to insert a new object into it.which stores songs information into it.
below is my table sturcture

```
song_id

song_title

song_description

Songs *aSong = (Poem *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Songs" inManagedObjectContext:myManagedObjectContext];
```

here i want to know how to check whether the song_id is already available before inserting the object again inside the table.

i mean before inserting the new object, how can i check for existence of it.

also how to check the table is empty?

Pls let me know and thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
NSError * error;
NSFetchRequest * checkExistance = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[checkExistance setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:NSStringFromClass([yourClass class]) inManagedObjectContext:yourManagedContext]];
[checkExistance setFetchLimit:1];
[checkExistance setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ID == %@", yourID]];
Songs *yourSong = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:checkExistance error:&error] lastObject];
```

now here if yourSong exists i.e. not null than it id exists.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. so you mean i can check like if ( yourSong ){ nslog@"song is avaialble already so skip inserting");} else{ nslog(@"save here");} am i right?

Comment: Here its give n take (morally) as we all are colleague by community members. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can get the entity from your managed object model using the **NSEntityDescription** method **entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:**.

Now **executeFetchRequest** method will provide array from which we can know record exits or not. Depending your requirement u can insert new record

Refer [Fetching Managed Objects](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFetching.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002484-SW1) link.